# Build an array with string index

Tags: javascript

I am trying to build an array with a custom string index to get the item faster. The console.log of arr2 is showing the 3 items wierdly but I can't enum them, it is only showing the first item.

I m using react so I can't build an object instead

```js
    let arr = [
       {
           "barcode": "27034FAZ019",
           "name": "Item 1",
           "price": 0.99,
           "stock": 10
       },
       {
           "barcode": "404E47HV1768",
           "name": "Item 2",
           "price": 2.99,
           "stock": 10
       },
       {
           "barcode": "325KS6130LG76",
           "name": "Item 3",
           "price": 5.99,
           "stock": 10
       }
    ]
      
    let arr2 = []
    arr.forEach((item) => {
       arr2[item.barcode] = item
    })
    
    console.log(arr2); //shows 3 items wierdly
    
    arr2.forEach((item) => {
       console.log(item); //shows only the first item
    })
```

The question is how to enum all the items in ***arr2*** because the forEach only output the first

Comment: Can you explain what is the question?

Comment: What results do you expect? You can edit and write a bit more :) Like: What I'm expected the final result is like this, like that.

Comment: Turned your code into a snippet. Use it in future when posting code

Comment: As you can see, the output you claim is different from what actually logs. Can you explain better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to set the key of objects within an array, instead of creating an object with keys,

i.e instead of

```
let arr2 = []
arr.forEach((item) => {
   arr2[item.barcode] = item
})
```

you would want:

```
let obj2 = {}
arr.forEach((item) => {
   obj2[item.barcode] = item
})
```

Comment: Im also wandering why he said  "I m using react so I can't build an object instead"

Comment: that looks correct but when I tried to build an object with defineProperty, I have an error passing this in props and when you build the object like an array, I have no error. So yes, I am still wandering too

Answer (score 0):

Create for this a object. To loop over the object you can loop with `for...in` Loop.

```js
arr = [
       {
           "barcode": "27034FAZ019",
           "name": "Item 1",
           "price": 0.99,
           "stock": 10
       },
       {
           "barcode": "404E47HV1768",
           "name": "Item 2",
           "price": 2.99,
           "stock": 10
       },
       {
           "barcode": "325KS6130LG76",
           "name": "Item 3",
           "price": 5.99,
           "stock": 10
       }
    ]
  
obj = {}
arr.forEach((item) => {  
  obj[item.barcode] = item;
})


console.log('arr2',obj);

for (key in obj) {
  console.log('item',obj[key], key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use map instead as below

```
  let arr = [
       {
           "barcode": "27034FAZ019",
           "name": "Item 1",
           "price": 0.99,
           "stock": 10
       },
       {
           "barcode": "404E47HV1768",
           "name": "Item 2",
           "price": 2.99,
           "stock": 10
       },
       {
           "barcode": "325KS6130LG76",
           "name": "Item 3",
           "price": 5.99,
           "stock": 10
       }
    ]
    
    let arr2 = new Map();
    arr.forEach(item => {
        arr2.set(item.barcode, item);
    })
    console.log(arr2);
    
    /*
     Map(3) {
  '27034FAZ019' => { barcode: '27034FAZ019', name: 'Item 1', price: 0.99, stock: 10 },
  '404E47HV1768' => { barcode: '404E47HV1768', name: 'Item 2', price: 2.99, stock: 10 },
  '325KS6130LG76' => { barcode: '325KS6130LG76', name: 'Item 3', price: 5.99, stock: 10 }
}
*/
    arr2.forEach(item => console.log(item));
    /*{ barcode: '27034FAZ019', name: 'Item 1', price: 0.99, stock: 10 }
{ barcode: '404E47HV1768', name: 'Item 2', price: 2.99, stock: 10 }
{ barcode: '325KS6130LG76', name: 'Item 3', price: 5.99, stock: 10 }*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You are currently setting additional properties on an array object. Which is not the intent of an array. An array is expected to be a numbered list, so is probably not the best fit.

I suggest a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instance, which is intended to hold key/value pairs. `Map` instances can also be easily iterated with a [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop or the [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach) method.

```js
const arr = [
   {
       "barcode": "27034FAZ019",
       "name": "Item 1",
       "price": 0.99,
       "stock": 10
   },
   {
       "barcode": "404E47HV1768",
       "name": "Item 2",
       "price": 2.99,
       "stock": 10
   },
   {
       "barcode": "325KS6130LG76",
       "name": "Item 3",
       "price": 5.99,
       "stock": 10
   }
];

const itemsByBarcode = new Map(arr.map(item => [item.barcode, item]));

// access a single value by barcode
console.log(itemsByBarcode.get("325KS6130LG76"));

// iterate through the Map instance with for...of loop
for (const [barcode, item] of itemsByBarcode) {
  console.log("for...of", barcode, item);
}

// iterate through the Map instance with forEach()
itemsByBarcode.forEach((item, barcode) => {
  console.log("forEach()", barcode, item);
});
```

---

You could also use an empty object instead of a `Map`. They can be iterated with [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) or you can first convert it back to an array with [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and then iterate it like you otherwise would.

However your standard object does have some hidden (non-iterable) properties like `toString`, `valueOf`, `constructor` and other standard properties (unless created with [`Object.create(null)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)).

If you intent to use an object solely for key/value data holding it's probably best to use `Object.create(null)` to initialize it. Or just use a `Map`, which is specifically designed to hold key/value pairs.

```js
const arr = [
   {
       "barcode": "27034FAZ019",
       "name": "Item 1",
       "price": 0.99,
       "stock": 10
   },
   {
       "barcode": "404E47HV1768",
       "name": "Item 2",
       "price": 2.99,
       "stock": 10
   },
   {
       "barcode": "325KS6130LG76",
       "name": "Item 3",
       "price": 5.99,
       "stock": 10
   }
];

const itemsByBarcode = Object.create(null);
for (const item of arr) {
  itemsByBarcode[item.barcode] = item;
}

// access a single value by barcode
console.log(itemsByBarcode["325KS6130LG76"]);

// iterate through the Map instance with for...of loop
for (const barcode in itemsByBarcode) {
  console.log("for...in", barcode, itemsByBarcode[barcode]);
}

Object.entries(barcode).forEach(([barcode, item]) => {
  console.log("Object.enties() + forEach()", barcode, item);
});
```

```
// although the default properties are skipped during iteration they can
// still for a problem if you want to check the presence.
const input = "constructor";

// check if a barcode is present in an object
if (input in itemsByBarcode) {
  // will run if `itemsByBarcode` was not created using Object.create(null)
  // ...
}

// vs

// check if a barcode is present in a Map
if (itemsByBarcode.has(input)) {
  // never runs (unless an actual barcode value is "constructor")
  // ...
}
```

I'd recommend you to check out the [Objects vs. Maps documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#objects_vs._maps) if you are interested in the differences.